# broken packages when installing mysql 5.6 using apt-get

Tags: amazon-ec2, apt, dependencies, mysql5.6

I am trying to install mySql 5.6 on my Linux machine.

I tried

```
>apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~) but 5.5.50-0+deb8u1 is to be installed           
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.30-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed


E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried:

```
apt-get install --fix-missing mysql-server-5.6
```

installing mysql 5.5 works fine.

but I am getting the same error

any ideas how to fix it?

I am using:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which distribution of Linux you are using.

Comment: @Charley I have updated the question.

Comment: And you're trying to use apt-get?!